# How to convert object to JSON when object have inner object

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutabledictionary, nsjsonserialization

I have custom class object that contains user object in it:

```
@interface Order : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *OrderId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Weight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) User *User
- (NSMutableDictionary *)toNSDictionary;
...
- (NSMutableDictionary *)toNSDictionary
{

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictionary setValue:self.OrderId forKey:@"OrderId"];
    [dictionary setValue:self.Title forKey:@"Title"];
    [dictionary setValue:self.Weight forKey:@"Weight"];

    return dictionary;
}
```

In `toNSDictinary` function I didn't mapped `User` object.
What is a good way to convert object to `nsdictionary` in situation like this?

Comment: be clear with ur question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `toNSDictionary` method:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)toNSDictionary
{

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictionary setValue:self.OrderId forKey:@"OrderId"];
    [dictionary setValue:self.Title forKey:@"Title"];
    [dictionary setValue:self.Weight forKey:@"Weight"];

    NSMutableDictionary *userDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [userDictionary setValue:self.User.someProperty1 forKey:@"someProperty1"];
    [userDictionary setValue:self.User.someProperty2 forKey:@"someProperty2"];
    [dictionary setValue:userDictionary forKey:@"User"];

    return dictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)toNSDictionary
{

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setValue:self.OrderId forKey:@"OrderId"];
[dictionary setValue:self.Title forKey:@"Title"];
[dictionary setValue:self.Weight forKey:@"Weight"];

NSMutableDictionary *userDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[userDictionary setValue:self.User.someProperty1 forKey:@"someProperty1"];
[userDictionary setValue:self.User.someProperty2 forKey:@"someProperty2"];
[dictionary setObject:userDictionary forKey:@"User"];

return dictionary;
}
```

while setting a dictionary for key try using

```
[dictionary   setObject: forKey: ]
```